# How to make iOS Control Center animations using flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, animation, flutter-animation

I need to implement an animation where a container grows in a pop-up (like the music player on the example). How can I do it using Flutter?
[image: ios Control Center animation]

Comment: It can be possible with using Hero widget with some dialog box. check out this https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations/hero-animations

Comment: @pixel I'm afraid that it would look differently, because I need exactly one container scales to another

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible with dialog with animation like this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQC50wCrL2o&ab_channel=FlutterGuys), but the dialog will only pushed from canter only.

If you want it to being pushed from the item's position itself then you need to use Hero widget with dialog. Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8Ot7wefZuc&ab_channel=HeyFlutter%E2%80%A4com), it have kind of similar thing. it would look just like an container scaling to an another container.

Comment: please accept the answer if you found it helpful.. reply if you need any other help.